# cocos2d-iphone: cocosbuilder: CCScrollView How to position

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am using CCScrollView provided by cocosBuilder. I am trying to position it in the center of the screen using this code:

```
CCSprite *testSrprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"category-shop1"];
testSprite.position = ccp(0,0);
CCScrollView *test = [[CCScrollView  alloc] initWithViewSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200) container:testSrprite];
test.position  = ccp(winsize.width/2,winsize.height/2);
[self addChild:test];
```

But this is not positioning the layer. Is it a bug in CCScrollView?

Comment: which scroller are you using? i don't think it is standard cocos2d thus there should be many versions.

Comment: if you have used cocosbuilder.. they provide one CCScrollView..